# Is it possible to upgrade the version of Flash used by the PS3's internal browser?

Tags: ps3, system-mods

PlayStation 3 has a built-in browser and I would like to use it. However, the version flash installed with it is old. How can I update it?

Answer (score 7):

Sony is the only company that can bless new software for use on the PS3.  If Sony has not released an official update to the PS3 firmware that contains an updated version of Flash, then it cannnot be updated without using [unauthorized firmware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40055/how-can-i-install-firefox-on-the-ps3).

Comment: Additionally, if Sony **have** released a new version, you will get it installed along with the other updates in the next system update. You can't select one bit or another, it's all or nothing.